# Axon - Always re-projecting all events

Tags: java, axon

Is it possible to use `usingSubscribingEventProcessors` and when it comes to projecting events, always re-project all events from beginning. Meaning - I never save projections to DB, but re-project all events whenever there is new event emitted from Aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

Of course that's possible!
You cannot achieve that by using the Subscribing Event Processor though.
You should leverage the Tracking Event Processor, but have an `InMemoryTokenStore` behind it. Doing so, the application can never start from where it left off, as the knowledge where it left off, the `TrackingToken`, does not exist.

Thus, you'd end up with your projections being recreated on start up, every time.

Another approach that you could take is a little different.
You'd still use a Tracking Event Processor, but with an actual persistent `TokenStore` implementation. Second, on start up of your application, you can issue a replay of the given Tracking Event Processor, by using the `TrackingEventProcessor#resetTokens()` function.

Taking this approach, you can add the `@ResetHandler` annotated function in your Event Handling Components to clear out the projection tables *prior* to handling all the events again.

Hope this gives you some insights Bojan!

Comment: I just made a setup with `InMemoryTokenStore` and `configurer.registerTokenStore("inMemoryProcessor", cfg -> inMemoryTokenStore());` and annotated projector with `@ProcessingGroup("inMemoryProcessor")`. Now what I can see is that tracking event processor is constantly polling for events from DB. Is it possible to make projection only on invoking `@QueryHandler` annotated method and not before? Basically, I send request of eg id=1 and this method knows that at that point in time it needs to reproject all events from this aggregate and return curent projection (without saving to db)?

Comment: OK, I just changed `queryResult.updates().blockFirst()` to `queryResult.initialResult().block()` and it seems to return correct result of projection.

Comment: it seems to return something which is I guess previous projection? If I use 'updates' it just hangs in a loop queuing `FROM
        DomainEventEntry e 
    WHERE
        e.globalIndex > :token`.

Comment: Yes, you could have the projection only being created when a query comes in on a `@QueryHandler` annotated functions. This will require some personal implementation though. Deep in it's internals Axon uses the `AnnotationEventListenerAdapter` to wrap an `@EventHandler` annotated class to be able to call it with an Event Stream.

You could wrap your projection in that, and on your `@QueryHandler` pull the event stream from the `EventStore` and handle this process yourself.

I've done this before, but only you can decide whether this home-work is desirable.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example of this? Also - any idea why updates() is not triggering in my case?

Comment: I don't have one ready made to share and to be honest do not have the time atm to create one for you. If you want more in depth Axon support, you could consider contacting AxonIQ directly i.o. the usergroup or StackOverlfow.
Regarding the updates, that's a function you only have if you use the subscription query approach in Axon: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/query-handling/dispatching-queries#subscription-queries

Answer (score 0):

@Steven What do you think about this solution?

```
public class ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor extends SubscribingEventProcessor {

  private final SubscribableMessageSource<? extends EventMessage<?>> messageSource;

  protected ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor(
      Builder builder) {
    super(builder);
    this.messageSource = builder.messageSource;
  }

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  /**
   * Whenever there is a need to process event messages, ignore all of them and since already inside messageSource,
   * just take all messages from event source and re-project all from beginning for this aggregate root
   * @param eventMessages
   */
  @Override
  protected void process(List<? extends EventMessage<?>> eventMessages) {
    try {
      //reprocess all previous events for this aggregate (get id from current event)
      GenericDomainEventMessage gdem = (GenericDomainEventMessage) eventMessages.get(0);
      List<? extends EventMessage<?>> prevEvs = ((EventStore)messageSource).readEvents(gdem.getAggregateIdentifier()).asStream()
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
      processInUnitOfWork(prevEvs, new BatchingUnitOfWork<>(prevEvs), Segment.ROOT_SEGMENT);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new EventProcessingException("Exception occurred while processing events", e);
    }
  }

  public static class Builder extends SubscribingEventProcessor.Builder{
    private SubscribableMessageSource<? extends EventMessage<?>> messageSource;

    @Override
    public Builder messageSource(
        SubscribableMessageSource<? extends EventMessage<?>> messageSource) {
      super.messageSource(messageSource);
      this.messageSource = messageSource;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor.Builder name(String name) {
      super.name(name);
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor.Builder eventHandlerInvoker(
        EventHandlerInvoker eventHandlerInvoker) {
      super.eventHandlerInvoker(eventHandlerInvoker);
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor.Builder processingStrategy(
        EventProcessingStrategy processingStrategy) {
      super.processingStrategy(processingStrategy);
      return this;
    }

    public ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor build() {
      return new ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor(this);
    }
  }
}
```

and config:

```
@Autowired
    public void configure(EventProcessingConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.registerEventProcessor("inMemoryProcessor",
                (n, c, ehi) -> replayingSubscribingEventProcessor(n, c, ehi, org.axonframework.config.Configuration::eventBus));
    }

    public ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor replayingSubscribingEventProcessor(
            String name,
            org.axonframework.config.Configuration conf,
            EventHandlerInvoker eventHandlerInvoker,
            Function<org.axonframework.config.Configuration, SubscribableMessageSource<? extends EventMessage<?>>> messageSource) {
        return ReplayingSubscribingEventProcessor.builder()
                .name(name)
                .eventHandlerInvoker(eventHandlerInvoker)
                .messageSource(messageSource.apply(conf))
                .processingStrategy(DirectEventProcessingStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .build();
    }
```